# uninitialized constant MiniTest::Test error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing

I am trying to get started with Minitest. I get the following error:

```
`const_missing': uninitialized constant MiniTest::Test (NameError)
```

This is my main code file:

```
class BmiCalc

    def initialize(weight, height)
        @weight = weight;
        @height = height;
    end

    def bmi
        kgweight = @weight * 0.4535;
        meterheight = @height * 0.01;
        bmivalue = kgweight/(meterheight * meterheight);
        return bmivalue;
    end

end

print "Please Enter your Weight in lbs: ";
weight = gets.to_f;

print "Please Enter your Height in cm: ";
height = gets.to_f;

bmiCalc = BmiCalc.new(weight, height);
answer = bmiCalc.bmi;

printf("You have a BMI of #{'%.2f' % answer} \n");
```

This is my MiniTest file:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative "bmicalc.rb"

class TestBmi < Minitest::Test

    def setup
        @bmicalc = BmiCalc.new(190, 250);
    end

    def test_answers
        assert_equal 31.40581717451523, @bmicalc.bmi;
    end

end
```

Firstly, I don't understand why it asks for input from me when I call this in the test file. I am instantiation a sample class already so why does it ask for input.

Secondly, I am not sure I understand the error or the nature of it. I am trying to follow this tutorial: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/short-introduction-minitest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why it asks for input from me when I call this in the test file

Because in your test file you require `"bmicalc.rb"`, which runs all code in it. Including your print and gets lines.

> I am not sure I understand the error or the nature of it

You didn't pay enough attention, perhaps? It's `Minitest::Test`, not `Minitest::test`.

Comment: Is there no way to avoid it running all the code (and make it visible for the test file)? Also I still get this: `const_missing': uninitialized constant MiniTest::Test (NameError)

Comment: @qaispak: again, not enough attention. Compare what you have with what I told you to use.

Comment: @qaispak: "Is there no way to avoid it running all the code" - there are ways, but the best thing here would be to not have that input-gathering code in that file. It has nothing to do with `BmiCalc` class/logic. Move it elsewhere (say, `program.rb`?)

Comment: Okay. Also, I am not sure about the error. I copied the code exactly as the link (from which I am learning) and get the same error. Might be I am missing a package for minitest?

Comment: @qaispak: I copy/pasted code from your current version of the question (sans the input/output part) and it worked. Did you forget to save the test file?